# How do I add another `views` folder to a Play Framework 2.1 app?

Tags: playframework, themes, sbt, directory-structure, playframework-2.1

I'd like to add another folder in which Play looks for Scala template files.

By default, Play finds templates in `app/views/`. I'd like to have Play look for views in another folder, `app/views-site-specific/`, too. Is that possible and how do I do it?

---

**Background:**

This `views-site-specific` folder would actually be a symbolic link to a parent directory of the Play app. The Play app is kept in a Git repository, and this parent directory is *another* Git repo, which stores site specific themes and customizations, symlinked to from inside the Play  app repo. In this way, I can avoid storing site specific stuff in the Play application itself. (It should be reused for many different sites, so I don't want any site specific stuff there.)

This is the layout of everything:

```
site-specific-git-repo/
  |
  +--play-2.1-application-git-repo/
  |    +--conf/
  |    +--public/
  |    +--app/
  |        +--controllers/
  |        +-- ...
  |        +--views/
  |        |   +--"built-in" Scala templates for e.g. admin pages
  |        |   +--themes/  -- bundled with app server, for E2E tests
  |        +--views-site-specific
  |              |
  |              |
  |              |
  +--themes/  <--` (symbolic link)
```

Comment: Since the views are actually compiled to `.class` files, can't you just have a dependency on them instead (using sbt)? Or maybe you can take advantage of [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Comment: @maba I don't know how a submodule would help? If I place it below the Play-2.1-app repo directory, its version (SHA1) would have to be checked in to the Play-2.1-app repo, and then it would no longer be possible to make site specific customizations.

Comment: @maba I'm not sure but doesn't Play itself via some SBT plugin compile only `.scala.html` files located inside app/views/ to `.class` files? Then I first need to tell Play to look for `scala.html` files outside the app/views/ folder, and compile them, otherwise there won't be any `.class` files to depend on?

Comment: I could softlink to [a Play project that contains site specific `.scala.template`s] located in the parent Git repo. That might work? But it feels like overkill to add a whole Play project, with `app`, `conf`, `public`, `project` directories, just to add some `views/` files.

Answer (score 1):

In Java (Play 2.3) it's possible to add views in any directory and access them by import, for example adding a view file called `test.scala.html` in the controllers directory, then

```java
import controllers.html.test;
// ...
return ok(test.render());
```

Importing several view-files from a sub-directory also works (here using `controllers/views/`)

```java
import controllers.views.html.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it's actually not possible (I don't know), I'm using a somewhat complicated workaround:
<sub>(You need to read the *Background* section in the OP for this to be interesting.)</sub>

I create two theme folders inside the app/views/ folder, and softlinked one of them to [a themes/ folder in a supposed parent Git repo]. Instead of trying to create *another* app/views/ folder.

One of these two theme folders is for built-in themes, the other is for site specific themes, like so:

```
site-specific-git-repo/
  |
  +--play-2.1-application-git-repo/
  |    +--conf/
  |    +--public/
  |    +--app/
  |        +--controllers/
  |        +-- ...
  |        +--views/
  |            +--..."built-in" Scala templates for e.g. admin pages
  |            +--themesbuiltin/
  |            |   +--default20121009  <— bundled with Play app, for E2E tests
  |            +--themes/     <— site specific, don't want in Play app Git repo
  |                |
  |                |
  +--themes/  <----` (symbolic link)
```

And my Scala code now becomes a little bit more complex: It searches both app/views/themesbuiltin/ and app/views/themes/ for Scala Template files. (Which Scala Template to use is specified in a config file, and at runtime it's found via reflection.)

However also CSS and JS would probably be located sometimes in 
`.../themesbuiltin/[theme-name]/styles.css` and sometimes in `.../themes/[theme-name]/styles.css`, and I have a feeling that this workaround makes the Scala code unnecessarily complex.